# No Unique URL for multiple pages, No XHR request made

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to download portfolio files for all the months, surfing through various pages, I tried to code this thing but facing these issues:
1) there is no xhr request made by url
2) no unique url for every page
3) the next button information in html has javascript form

Kindly code this thing, i have spent about two days over this problem

the link for the website is "https://www.barodamf.com/Downloads/Pages/Latest-Factsheet-and-Profile.aspx"

Comment: Please provide some code snippets so we can help you solve your problem!

Comment: I couldn't exactly code much because i don't know how to get the url for next button in the website, it's hidden in dopost javascript